# my iOS application does not handle image file type in all application

Tags: ios

I want my app to be in 'Open in' options for image.

I have used this code in my Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.image</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PNG image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>JPEG image</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

In the application 'Inbox', on sharing an image, i can see my app 'Quotle' :

[image]

But in Apple's application 'Photo', i don't see my app :

[image]

What can i do to see my app in sharing menu into application 'Photo'?

Comment: u need to show your app in share Extension ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to show your app in Photo's Share to list, you need to add a new target of Share Extension into your project, please refer the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1) for more info on how to add the Share Extension.

Comment: That's what i did in fact